# What is the role of pratico in this phrase?

Tags: nouns

I was reading this phrase:

> pratico regolabile e preciso nella tostatura

and in translation to English I got

> practical adjustable and precise in toasting

with two adjectives beside each other. Is it correct Italian or is the translation incorrect?

Comment: The adjectives *Pratico* and *practical* should be considered false friends, although “pratico” can be used with the same meaning as “practical”, for example in the title “Critica della ragion pratica”.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here *pratico* means *handy* or *convenient*. Also, the original sentence should be

> Pratico, regolabile e preciso nella tostatura.